# Trying to create a dropdown list and textbox, setting list item as data and text box as value - asp.net mvc 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to create a search form that searches based on Server Name or Printer Name. Here is the snippet from my controller:

```
List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Server Name", Value = "ServerName" });
        items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Printer Name", Value = "PrinterName" });

        ViewData["newlist"] = items;
```

Here is my view (which I know is wrong because it doesn't work):

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("search", "PrintQueues", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>
            Search
        </legend>

    @Html.DropDownList("newlist",ViewData["newlist"] as SelectList)
    @Html.TextBox("newlist")
    <p> 
       <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </p>
    </fieldset> 
}
```

If I pick "Server Name" and put in a value (such as "myservernaem" into the textbox, I want the url to show:

```
/search?ServerName=myservername
```

I'm pretty sure both my controller and view are incorrect.

Comment: you sure you don't want it to show `myservernaem` you have a typo lol

Comment: why would you want to pass it as a query string wouldn't it be easier to just use the formm collection on you post controller

Comment: Because it's a simple search which can be bookmarked with the query string. I use posts for writing data. This is a simple read.

Comment: but based on you example you are not even building a query string how do you expect it to work????

Comment: It does build a query string, it's just wrong. It says newlist=Server Name&newlist="whatever is in my text box". Can you help?

Comment: one think you really do not want it to have the same name newlist there twice

Answer (score 0):

Not a huge fan of this approach... Http works by sending a value for each `input` to your controller. From the values you receive in your controller, you should be able to return the appropriate page and information.

So if you re-named your drop down list to *searchType* and your textbox to *searchCriteria* you'd have a nice query string like: `/Search?searchType=Printer&searchCriteria=epson`. In your controller you should then be able to receive these and return the appropriate page (whether it be a printer or server).

```
public ActionResult Search(string searchType, string searchCriteria)
{
    if(searchType == "PrinterName")
    {
        // search your printers using searchCriteria and return appropriate View
    }
    else if(searchType == "ServerName")
    {
        // search your servers using searchCriteria and return appropriate View
    }
}
```

If you go with this approach you could create an `enum` called *SearchType* and use that instead of `string`, which would allow you to do: `if(searchType == SearchType.Printer)` ...

If you want to go with your approach, you could get the values from your inputs when you try to search and append a URL:

```
@Html.DropDownList("searchType",ViewData["newlist"] as SelectList)
@Html.TextBox("searchCriteria")
<button type="button" onclick="GoToSearch();">Search</button>

function Search() {

    // assumption of jquery (use document.getElementById otherwise...)
    var type = $('#searchType').val();
    var searchCriteria = $('#searchCriteria').val();

    window.location = '@Url.Action("Search", "PrintQueues")' + '?' + type + '=' + searchCriteria;
}
```

Happy to answer any questions.